# AWS-IAM: Automating disabling access keys and accounts that violate password policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have password policies in place that require users to rotate their passwords and CLi/API access keys every 90 days. We use AWS Inspector and it sends us reports regularly. The issue is, we have to manually disable accounts when the reports flag them. Is there a way, through a tool or policy that we can automate this?

Comment: Report -> S3 -> Lambda and then disable?

Comment: What 'passwords' are you referencing? I thought that AWS Inspector looks at the contents of EC2 instances. It does not look at IAM credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your Inspector to post to SNS, and hook that into Lambda. These links should point you in the right direction.

[How to remediate Amazon Inspector Security Findings Automatically](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-remediate-amazon-inspector-security-findings-automatically/)

[How to rotate access keys for IAM users](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-rotate-access-keys-for-iam-users/) (Passwords can be changed with CLI too)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic remediation with [AWS config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/remediation.html) is another option.

I think the detection is out of the [box](https://console.aws.amazon.com/config/). The remediation would be custom. Something like put user in [disabled group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#removeUserFromGroup-property) or send [sns notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html) depending on how proactive you want to be and execute that through a Lambda.